# Ink in water Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

how can I best replicate an ink-in-water effect in Photoshop CS6? I'm guessing the best way is most probably to use brushes.

The following image is a good example of what I wan't to achieve:

[image]

Thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

There are most definitely many different ways of achieving that effect. Personally I would try creating multiple layers of "smoke". Let's try and find some tutorials for this!

Simply searching psd.tutsplus.com for 'smoke' and 'ink in water' turns up a lot of relevant tutorials.

Here is one that should help you get there (digital smoke):
http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials-effects/digital-smoke-in-photoshop/?search_index=2

Here are some already-made brushes of ink droplets:
http://psd.tutsplus.com/freebies/brushes/exclusive-freebie-pack-%E2%80%93-25-ink-brushes/?search_index=1

Another fairly relevant brush-set:
http://psd.tutsplus.com/freebies/brushes/smoke-brush-set/?search_index=1

Another tutorial that could prove helpful:
http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/photo-effects-tutorials/manipulate-smoke-to-create-hyper-real-images/?search_index=8

There you go! Have a look at a tutorial, try to see what you can use and start experimenting yourself! That's really the best way to learn with Photoshop.